# Grant select on view paradox in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have 2 databases and i have a table on one of this database and view is on the another database. For example `table` is `blackshire.dbo.table` and `view` is `whiteshire.dbo.view`. And i have user which name of emrep and emrep hasnt got select privilege on `blackshire.dbo.table`. Thatswhy my view is created without some column. When i give select privilige on view to emrep i getting error

```
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'table', database 'blackshire', schema 'dbo'.
```

I really confused and i cant figure it out. When i search some resource says that it can be possible but only with some procedure etc.

Can someone help and explain to me please ?

Comment: what does is mean "view is created without some column" ? You need SELECT permissions on target table

Comment: i mean view not including all column as table cause of some column information is private.

Comment: You need to consider the ownership chains of your databases.  See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1782/understanding-cross-database-ownership-chaining-in-sql-server/

Comment: here is a production system, is there any risk to use this ownership chaining ? Is there any other way to make it possible this ?

Comment: Yes, @GeorgeWidgi, there are risks to using database ownership chaining. Microsoft discusses this in their own documentation on [Ownership Chains](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676(v=sql.105).aspx#Anchor_3).